# método getDay() Ionic dentro e fora do construtor, erro! - Typescript

Tags: html, funções, ionic

Boa tarde pessoal, este é o meu primeiro post aqui no stackoverflow então ja peço desculpas caso haja algum erro..

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: estou trabalhando com Ionic e estou precisando "pegar" o dia da semana e transformar em um número para poder trabalhar com condicionais pra esse valor, pra isso existe o método getDay() que retorna um valor de 0 a 6.. até aí ok!
Quando eu coloco dentro do construtor como a print abaixo:[image]

A função retorna o valor normalmente!!! Sem erros ao correr

Agora, quando eu tento criar uma função fora do construtor, chamando o método getDay(), assim: [image]

Na parte do html eu coloco (click)="refresh()" em um botão para repassar o valor retornado pela getDay para a variável dia, dá um erro dizendo que a "getDay()" is not a function.
Porque no construtor dá certo, e fora não?

@edit
código .ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker';

/**
 * Generated class for the AdicionaPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-adiciona',
  templateUrl: 'adiciona.html',
})
export class AdicionaPage {
  
  today = new Date();
  semana = ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"]
  listaDia = Array;
  listaMes = Array;
  dia;
  mes;
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  
}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AdicionaPage');
  }


  refresh(){
    this.dia = this.semana[this.today.getDate()];
  }



}
```

```html
<!--
  Generated template for the AdicionaPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Adiciona</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <ion-list>
        <h2>Paciente</h2>  
    
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nome"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        <button clear ion-button>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-datetime placeholder="Data" displayFormat="DD MMM de YYYY" min="2018" [(ngModel)]="today"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
          {{dia}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
      <button ion-button large color="secondary" class="botao" (click)="refresh()">
        Salvar
      </button>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: Coloque o **código** ao invés de imagem, assim fica mais fácil e rápido ajuda-ló. Leia: [Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: Não sei aonde está realmente seu problema, fiz o teste aqui e funciona normalmente. veja em [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sjdz2c) ... Veja seu método está `this.dia = this.semana[this.today.getDate()];` quando era pra estar `this.dia = this.semana[this.today.getDay()];`

Comment: Então wmsouza.. eu estava tentando com getDay e o erro era o mesmo! Mudei para getDate apenas a fim de teste